# BCP Global temporary table data - Unable to create format file and export data

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am able to create format file and export data if global temp table is created beforehand but the same doesn't work if I'm creating table dynamically, using INTO clause.

This works perfectly fine

```
IF OBJECT_Id('tempdb..##TmpTable1') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE ##TmpTable1 END
go

CREATE TABLE ##TmpTable1(Id int, Val varchar(100))
go

INSERT INTO ##TmpTable1(Id,Val) VALUES(1,'A'),(2,'B')
go
```

```
bcp tempdb.##TmpTable1 format nul -c -t"|" -f "C:\TmpTable1.fmt" -S MyDBServerName -T
bcp tempdb.##TmpTable1 OUT "C:\TmpTable1.out" -c -t"|" -S MyDBServerName -T
```

but this doesn't work.

```
SELECT Id,Val
INTO ##TmpTable1
FROM Table1
go
```

The command is stuck, and if I kill it then following error is displayed

> Assertion failed: 0 == m_event, file sql\common\include\eventhandle.hpp, line 305

Appreciate if someone could highlight the problem.

Comment: Which command is "stuck"? the BCP command? I suggest you use sp_who2 to investigate why it's "stuck"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid neither BCP format works, nor OUT. I will check `sp_who2` output.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `sp_who2` isn't showing any blocker or useful information.

Comment: How long do you let BCP run for?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid BCP Format for couple of minutes. BCP OUT will take time due to volume but I first need format file.

Comment: Depending on your requirements you may not need a format file

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I need it. Possible there is some blocker in DB which isn't visible via `sp_who`, I will check.

Comment: You can get a lot more useful info, if indeed it's an issue with blocking or resources, by using *sp_WhoIsActive*

Comment: Agreed sp_WhoIsActive is far better.

Comment: Why do you need a format file? If you're going to read that data back into an SQL Server instance have you tried using native format? Have you considered creating a persistent table in the tempdb database instead of trying to use a global temp table? How are you launching the bcp Utility? If you're trying to start it using `xp_cmdshell` or other shell tricks from inside the same transaction... it's going to be blocked by your transaction until it commits, but it will not commit until bcp finishes, but bcp will be blocked by your transaction until it commits... ad nauseam.